# Which class the interface type instance is from

Tags: java

I have an interface:

```
public interface Myinterface{
  ...
}
```

The interface is implemented by three classes, let's name them `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo`, `ClassThree`.

Now, I have a helper method which returns an instance of type `MyInterface`. e.g.

```
MyInterface myInstance = MyHelper.getOneInstance();
```

I what to check whether the returned instance `myInstance` is a instance of `ClassThree` or not, how to do it in Java?

(I know there is `instanceof` keyword in Java, but it is checking the other way around. I want to know which concrete class the instance is from.)

Comment: What about ``myInstance.getClass()``?

Comment: `getClass` like everyone is telling you although this sounds like a lousy design. Why have that interface if you're just going to ignore it and start digging down the type hierarchy at runtime anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether an object is an instance of a specific class, you can use the `getClass()` method from the `Object` class.

For example this is true only if `myInstance` is a `ClassThree` object:

```
if (myInstance.getClass() == ClassThree.class)
```

Now, generally this is not necessarily more robust as it defeats some of the benefits of OOP.
A more OOP way to proceed is introducing a method that you could use to do this check.

As you don't give a specific example, it is hard to give an adapted example but assume that you want to save some classes if these are recordable. 

You could introduce a `boolean isRecordable()` method in your interface.

In this way you could do :

```
if (myInstance.isRecordable()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like the second part of your answer where you suggest adding a method to the interface instead of using the type of object. However getClass tends to fall down very quickly when you extend code. If I make a ClassFour that extends ClassThree, your implementation in the first part of your post breaks unless you also change the check to also look for ClassFour (coupling).

Comment: @Sam I agree totally. The first part doesn't show the right way. I explain only how the Java language allow to check whether an  object is an instance of a specific class.  The second part is much longer to stress on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure `instanceof ClassThree` is true if `getOneInstance()` returns a ClassThree object.

```
    while (true){
        MyInterface impl = MyHelper.getOneInstance()();
        if(impl instanceof Class1){
            System.out.println("was 1");
        } else if(impl instanceof Class2){
            System.out.println("was 2");
        } else if(impl instanceof Class3){
            System.out.println("was 3");
        }
    }
```

The difference between `instanceof` and `getClass()` implementations is that instanceof will look up the hierarchy so

`new ClassThree() instanceof MyInterface` is true whereas,

`new ClassThree().getClass() == MyInterface.class` is false.

Comment: this breaks if Class3 is extending Class2

Comment: Correct, I made the assumption that the classes given are only implementing `MyInterface`. This does continue to work if another class extends one of the initial three unlike `getClass()` solutions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [visitor pattern](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/visitor)

Often you don't want to know the implementing class name, but want to have the correct behaviour ensured.
The visitor pattern is a layer of indirection, with its own pitfalls, but generally speaking often the way to go.

I think it is better than `instance of` because sometimes your object is an instance of different classes/interfaces and therefore your check must be considering all possible combinations and not return early. 
Another downside is, that if you use `getClass()` your code will become cluttered with `if`s accross your project, whereas the Visitor gives you a central place.

```
public interface MyVisitor<T> {
    T visitClassOne(ClassOne classOne);
    T visitClassTwo(ClassTwo classTwo);
    T visitClassThree(ClassThree classThree);
}

public interface MyInterface {
    Class acceptVisitor(MyVisitor myVisitor);
}

public class ClassOne implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    Class acceptVisitor(MyVisitor myVisitor) {
        return myVisitor.visitClassOne(this);
    }
}


//or maybe call the desired methods directly, instead of returning the 
//Class an call the desired methods based on the result. 
public class ClassVisitor implements MyVisitor<Class> {
    @Override
    Class visitClassOne(ClassOne classOne) {
        return classOne.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    Class visitClassTwo(ClassTwo classTwo) {
        return classTwo.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    Class visitClassThree(ClassThree classThree) {
        return classThree.getClass();
    }
}
```

so sowhere else you could do:

```
MyInterface myClass = new ClassOne();
Class myClassClass = myClass.acceptVisitor(new ClassVisitor());
```

this is untestet, I just wrote it down.
I have to admit for returning `Class` this is not the tiptop very best idea, but as already said, often you don´t want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "is" keyword? if (myInstance is ClassThree) { . . . }

Comment: Which language are you speaking? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Oh sorry. That's for c#